# Get Products supporting all delivery modes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

I have a table **ProductDeliveryModes** as:

```
ProductId    DeliveryId
P101         D1
P101         D2
P101         D3
P102         D1
P102         D2
P102         D3
P103         D1
```

I need to get products which support all delivery modes (D1, D2, D3). From looking at the table the products should be: P101 and P102.

The query that I formed to get the solution is:

```
SELECT ProductId
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ProductId,
                        DeliveryId
        FROM   ProductDeliveryModes) X
WHERE  X.DeliveryId IN ( 'D1', 'D2', 'D3' )
GROUP  BY ProductId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

The problem that I see in my solution is that one should know the count of the total number of delivery modes. We could make the count dynamic by getting the count from Sub-query.

Is there a better solution ?

Comment: "better solution" with respect to what? Maintainability? Efficiency? If the latter what is the table definition including indexes? Also is there another table with the distinct delivery modes? You might find the following articles useful though. [one](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) [two](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/07/02/Proper-Relational-Division-With-Sets.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `DISTINCT` with `COUNT` function to get the same result:

```
SELECT [ProductID]
FROM ProductDeliveryModes
GROUP BY  [ProductID]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [DeliveryId]) = 3
```

Check the [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1ccf/3).

You can simple store the distinct delivery count in a variable and used it. If you need to do this in a single query, this is one of the possible ways:

```
WITH CTE (DeliveryCount) AS 
(
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [DeliveryID])
   FROM DataSource
)  
SELECT [ProductID]
FROM DataSource
CROSS APPLY CTE
GROUP BY [ProductID]
        ,CTE.DeliveryCount
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [DeliveryID]) = DeliveryCount
```

See the [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1ccf/19).

Comment: Huh, good idea. I was about to propose using a table variable to store the distinct DeliveryID's there, but this is better. :)

Comment: @Kahn, actually the table variable is good alternative because in some cases the `CTE` can lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this below query for better performance.

```
 ;WITH CTE_Product
 AS
 (
        SELECT DISTINCT ProductID 
        FROM ProductDeliveryModes
 ),CTE_Delivery
 AS
 (
        SELECT DISTINCT DeliveryId 
        FROM ProductDeliveryModes
 )

 SELECT * 
 FROM CTE_Product C
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
     SELECT 1 
     FROM CTE_Delivery D
     LEFT JOIN ProductDeliveryModes T ON T.DeliveryId = D.DeliveryId AND T.ProductId=C.ProductId 
     WHERE T.ProductID IS NULL
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query just a bit to get the actual count of distinct delivery methods:

```
SELECT ProductID
FROM ProductDeliveryModes
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING COUNT(*) =
   (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT DeliveryId) FROM ProductDeliveryModes)
```